# Cross-platform GUI application console for debug messages C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I am programming a game in C++. I want to print debugging messages from within my code using std::cout, but as this is a GUI application there is no console to print to by default. I have tried simply running it from CMD like this:

```
start Debug/hydro.exe
```

But to no avail.

On Windows 8 x86_64 using Visual Studio 2012 with a Win32 project, the following code achieves what I am looking for:

```
#include <Windows.h>
...
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN$", "r",stdin);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w",stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w",stderr);
```

However, I believe that this not cross-platform (do correct me if I am wrong!) and would like my application to work on Linux and Mac OS X.

Is there a cross-platform solution to this? Of course, the simpler the better!

Comment: Just run the program from a terminal window if you want "console" debug messages, and use `std::cout`? That's how most programs (games or others) does it.

Comment: I tried this (this is how I solved the program on Linux), but nothing gets printed. I am using std::cout already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any product that does this in a Linux world - you are expected to start the code from a shell, and the output appears in the shell window.

Wrapping like this should help:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
// Windows-only code here
#endif
```

When outside of Windows, the code will not be compiled, when inside of the Windows the code will be compiled!

Comment: That's one macro that works, yes. I was hoping that I could convey the principle without having to look up what the relevant macro is called.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your code depends on `<Windows.h>` it is DEFINITELY NOT cross-platform.

Take a look at [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/) for cross-platform logging. It's a pretty stable, mature platform.

PS: Good luck with cross-platform GUI programming. GUI programming is typically very platform-specific. A framework like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) will probably help a lot, and if you are doing 3D graphics, be sure to use OpenGL rather than DirectX.

Comment: I am using SFML at the moment, although I am interested in Qt too! I shall take a look at log4cxx now, thank you! If it works, I'll mark this as the solution.

Comment: The other solution works for me, and is far easier. Thank you though!

Comment: @JoshuaGerrard not being a Windows programmer, I think I might have misunderstood your problem. You're right that log4cxx doesn't really address your problem as I understand it now. It might still be nice for you to use it though _on top of_ the other solution to get fancier logging than just using standard out/error.

Comment: Yeah it does look interesting, so it was still a useful bit of information :)